# How to print space between integers to a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to print to a textfile, but I keep getting this output :

```
array = ('0', '0', '0', '0')
```

the desired output I want is

```
array = 0 0 0 0
```

here is the code snippet im having problems with.

```
nonCharge_reference = self.ui.nonCharge_reference_textbox.text()
    nonCharge_Engine_1 = self.ui.nonCharge_engine1_textbox.text()
    nonCharge_Engine_2 = self.ui.nonCharge_engine2_textbox.text()
    nonCharge_Engine_3 = self.ui.nonCharge_engine3_textbox.text()
print(f'#',
"\n"f'array = {nonCharge_reference, nonCharge_Engine_1, nonCharge_Engine_2,nonCharge_Engine_3,}'
```

Comment: `' '.join(array)` will create a space-separated string

Answer (score 1):

Don't put them in a single `{}`. That's creating a tuple and then printing that. Format each variable separately.

```
print(f'#\narray = {nonCharge_reference} {nonCharge_Engine_1} {nonCharge_Engine_2} {nonCharge_Engine_3}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<string>.join(<array>)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **join** method to concatenate those items in a string. This way: `str_array =  " ".join(array)`. This will concatenate elements in the array, separating them by an space " ". *str_array* will have that value. For more info, check out the documentation at [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)